# .NET Minimal API: how to map all route and all verb in the same handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Our team maintains a huge repository containing multiple applications that have been started more than 10 years ago. The strategy at that time was to create classes that implement `IHttpHandler` and the method `public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` handle every request.

Minimal API seems to be an excellent way for us to upgrade .NET from 4.8 to 6.0 because we are in a regulated environment and this will do minimal code change.

Unfortunately, we were not able to reproduce a way to mimic IHttpHandler or NodeJS, to bind all route and verb to the same method.

Example in NodeJS:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Is there a way in Minimal Api to do this? So in the function we could access the request/response and do some manual routing like:

```
switch (request.Method)
{
case "GET"
   response.Write("This is a get");
   break;
case "POST"
   response.Write("This is a post");
   break;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by using [`EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.Map`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.map?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-endpointroutebuilderextensions-map(microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-iendpointroutebuilder-microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-patterns-routepattern-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-requestdelegate)) method, for example:

```cs
app.Map("/test", async (HttpContext context, CancellationToken ct)
    => await Results.Json(new { test = context.Request.Method }).ExecuteAsync(context));
```

But I would argue that possibly you should look into custom [ASP.NET Core middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which to my understanding are closer to `IHttpHandler`'s. Simple one can look like:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var request = context.Request;
    if (request is ...) // some predicate to filter request
    {
        await Results.Json(new { test = context.Request.Method }).ExecuteAsync(context);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```